# Getting source code from page AFTER jQuery function in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to get the source code from [this page](http://www.cinesion.ch/horaires), to get the code of the timetables, and then parse it.

But when I fetch it with `file_get_contents`, the `div` I'm looking for is **empty**. I searched in the code, and it looks like it's filled with `jQuery` when to body is loaded.

So my question is : how can I get the source code of the page after the jQuery is executed ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the information you want comes from this page http://www.cinesion.ch/cinesion/timetable.php through an AJAX request so file_get_contents will never get it unless you do the call directly to this page...

try this one
http://www.cinesion.ch/cinesion/timetable.php?date=%&movie=%&city=%&_JEXEC=1

Comment: I just want to fetch the timetables, then insert them in a database. After that I have coded an Android application that is displaying the movies for today, or any specified days.
I am currently fetching the datas from http://www.cinesion.ch/mobile/, but there isn't all the timetables, just for 2 or 3 days.

Answer (score 2):

Since jQuery is javascript, php's `file_get_contents` will not help because it does not execute javascript.

Either find out which ajax data they load and use them directly, or use a browser ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I noticed that `file_get_contents` just gets the text of the page.
@mars find a way to fetch the datas.